# How to add extra filed details in email message

Tags: php, swiftmailer, mailer

i want to add one more filed for mobile no. but its not getting in email

```
    ->setFrom(array($sender_email => $site_name))
    ->setTo($listing_owner_email)
    ->setBody($sender_msg)
    ->setBody2($sender_mobile) (i added mobile field)
    ->setReplyTo($sender_email)
    ->setReturnPath($admin_email)
```

Comment: Why the xcode tag? and where do these methods belong?

Comment: Which library are you using ??

Comment: Hi, i am using swiftmailer

Answer (score 0):

In Swiftmailer there doesn't exists a method that lets you add a "body2"...
You can add the phone number to the **body** just doing

```
->setBody($sender_msg . $sender_mobile);
```

The method body2 isn't mentioned at all in [Swiftmailer docs](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html).

As I can understand you have a form where people can write their phone number, but you can't create a method that doesn't exist.
So with this code you add the phone number to the body of the email. This way, you will get the variable.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Can you set the answer as the right one?